# Stored procedure with parameters in Access

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2013

I have this stored procedure that I run in Access.

```
Private Sub ReviewTrns_Click()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
        Set cdb = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")

        qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_FreeShipping").Connect
        qdf.SQL = "EXEC dbo.UpdateTrns"

        qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
        qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set cdb = Nothing
MsgBox "Records Updated!"

End Sub
```

It works perfectly. `dbo_FreeShipping` is a linked table, `dbo.UpdateTrns` is a stored procedure. I also want to add input value for parameter `@variable1`

Could it be done with message box input?

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the result of the user input on to your sql call. Try something like :

```
Private Sub ReviewTrns_Click()

  Dim input As String
  input = InputBox("Enter variable1") //get the user input

  Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Set cdb = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")

  qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_FreeShipping").Connect
  qdf.SQL = "EXEC dbo.UpdateTrns @variable1='" & input & "'" // concatenate parameter

  qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
      qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
      Set qdf = Nothing
      Set cdb = Nothing

  MsgBox "Records Updated!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

my goto method for getting input variables from an alert box in vba is `InputBox()`. e.g.:

```
Public myStr as String

public sub GetInputStr()
    myStr = InputBox("Enter your variable here")
end sub
```

you should then be able to use myStr in other subs within your module. hope this helps!